# Use Matlab to Call System Function Asynchronously in background

Tags: matlab, asynchronous, dos

I can use Matlab to call a system function as follows:

```
system('dir');
```

this displays the results on the standard output of matlab and runs synchronously.

I can capture the output in a variable by using:

```
[status,stdout]  = dos('dir');
```

This displays no output, but still runs synchronously.

I can run the script *asynchronously* by using;

```
system('dir &');
```

This pops up a command window which then runs in the foreground and remains open when the function is complete.

What I *would like to do* is run the command asynchronously **in the background** and close when it is finished.  Is there a way to do this?

I'm on windows 7

Comment: You might be able to do this with a batch file.

Comment: @m_power Agreed -- that should work.  I was wondering if there was a cleaner way than having matlab call a batch file to call another command

Comment: What's the specific use case you have in mind? The `dir` looks like a toy example. Different cases may need different mechanisms. Why do you need asynchronous behavior? Is it going to be a long-running process? And what do you mean by `in the background`? Just without a visible command window? Or behind the other windows? (In Unix, `background` has a specific meaning without a direct Windows equivalent.)

Comment: @AndrewJanke You're right, `dir` is a toy example.   I'm actually calling an exe that I wrote which captures an image from a camera.  I'm using matlab to repeatedly (every second) capture an image and do not need or want a screen popping up every second.  Without a visible command window would be preferred.  Minimized or behind other windows would also be acceptable. I'm used running unix systems -- I'm using windows begrudgingly right now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the Windows `start` command to get better control over how the new process is launched. It will launch a new process and return. For example:

```
[status,out] = system('start /b /min myprogram.exe');
```

If the `start` options aren't enough for you, you can use the Java `java.lang.Process` or .NET `System.Diagnostics.Process` classes to more directly launch a process from code. Both can be called directly from Matlab code and will allow you to launch a new process, have it run asynchronously, and check in on its status. Basically, this is an alternative to Matlab's `system()` which will give you finer-grained control over the process you're launching. In particular, the .NET one will let you specify window state, whether to use the shell to process the command, and so on. And IIRC, the Java one is sufficient to launch a win32 console app (which I assume your exe is compiled as) without a new window appearing.

If you wanted to do some additional monitoring and interaction with the process, and are willing to write some Java code, you could run the process from a new Java worker thread in Matlab's embedded JVM.

Answer (score 3):

Use Matlab's [Timer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer.html) object. It runs asynchronously. You can also specify the exit function `StopFcn`.

Comment: Are you sure this works? The `Timer` object runs asynchronously, but when it expires, its callback function runs effectively synchronously in the single-threaded Matlab interpreter like GUI callbacks do - it'll either suspend execution of whatever called `pause` or `drawnow`, or maybe get starved. May not be appropriate for long-running tasks. (This isn't very explicit in the Matlab docs, but http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/using-a-matlab-timer-object.html alludes to it in the "Note" sidebar.) So if you're doing `dos('dir')`, it won't be "in the background".

Comment: @AndrewJanke Andrew -- I think you're exactly right.  I tried using Matlab's timer object and it doesn't *exactly* work for the reasons you've stated.

Comment: @Prashant Thanks for checking in.  The answer is not complete.  I prefer to wait a day or two before accepting an answer to make sure it is indeed the most correct answer available per the advice in your link ' if there are answers that are good enough but that you're not entirely satisfied by, you might wait 24 to 48 hours to give other people a chance to give you a better answer. A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer'

Comment: I think that in the newer versions of Matlab there is a bug with callback functions declaration like `t.StopFcn = {@disp, 'stopped'}`. I remember in older version it worked. There should be a workaround, maybe i'll post it.